# Check if two variadic derived classes are instantiated with the same parameter pack

Tags: c++11

In situations, when you have a base and many derived classes, all of which encode a variadic pack, something like the following

```
template<typename ... Args>
struct base
{};

template<typename ... Args>
struct derived_1: base <Args...>
{};
template<typename ... Args>
struct derived_2: base <Args...>
{};
```

How does one check if objects of different derived classes were instantiated using the same pack. For instance given

```
derived_1<int,float,double> d1_obj;
derived_2<int,float,double> d2_obj;
```

I want a mechanism to tell me that both objects are equal, in the sense that they contain the same types in the same order.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this using template template parameters and partial specialization for when arguments match:

```
template <class T, class U>
struct same_args : std::false_type{};

template <template <typename...> class T, template <typename...> class U,
          typename... Ts>
struct same_args<T<Ts...>, U<Ts...>> : std::true_type{};
```

Then `same_args<derived_1<int,float>, derived_2<int,float>>::value` will be `true`.

[<kbd>Live Demo</kbd>](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5dd28b8326fe0653)