# SFINAE: Check whether the concatenation of two variadic packs is the same as one pack

Tags: templates, c++14, variadic-templates, template-meta-programming, sfinae

Is there a way to check whether the concatenation of two variadic argument packs is the same as a third variadic argument pack.

```
template<typename... Args>
struct ClassOne
{
}

template<typename... Args>
struct ClassTwo
{
}

template<typename... Args>
struct ClassThree
{
}

template<typename... PackA, typename... PackB, typename... PackC>
void foo(ClassOne<PackA...>, ClassTwo<PackB...>, ClassThree<PackC...>)
{
}
```

I would like foo to only be enabled if PackA... = PackB..., PackC...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Check if two variadic derived classes are instantiated with the same parameter pack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37435575/check-if-two-variadic-derived-classes-are-instantiated-with-the-same-parameter-p)

Comment: I'm looking to compare the concatenation of the argument packs though, and I forgot to mention the classes are unrelated, sorry updated it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Rather straightforward...

```
template <typename ...>
struct pack{};

template<typename... PackA, typename... PackB, typename... PackC,
  typename = typename std::enable_if
     <std::is_same<pack<PackA...>, 
                   pack<PackB..., PackC...>>::value
     >::type>
void foo(ClassOne<PackA...>, ClassTwo<PackB...>, ClassThree<PackC...>)
{
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, create a `pack` class to store a bunch of types:

```
template <typename... Ts> struct pack { };
```

Then, write a function to check if two packs are the same:

```
template <typename P0, typename P1>
struct are_packs_same;

template <typename... T0s, typename... T1s>
struct are_packs_same<pack<T0s...>, pack<T1s...>>
    : std::bool_constant<(sizeof...(T0s) == sizeof...(T1s)) 
                      && (std::is_same_v<T0s, T1s> && ...)>
{
};
```

Lastly, you need a function to concatenate two packs:

```
template <typename P0, typename P1>
struct concat_packs;

template <typename... T0s, typename... T1s>
struct concat_packs<pack<T0s...>, pack<T1s...>>
{
    using type = pack<T0s..., T1s...>;
};
```

Example usage:

```
int main()
{
    using p0 = pack<int, char>;
    using p1 = pack<float>;
    using p2 = pack<int, char, float>;

    static_assert(are_packs_same<
        typename concat_packs<p0, p1>::type,
        p2>::value);
}
```

[**live wandbox example**](https://wandbox.org/permlink/aqRX2SwlTuuE8QYB)

Comment: How can you not write constexpr == on pack.  I mean morally.

Answer (score 1):

```
template<class...> struct types{
  friend constexpr std::true_type operator==(types,types) { return {}; }
  template<class...Ts>
  friend constexpr std::false_type operator==(types,types<Ts...>) { return {}; }
  constexpr types(){}
  template<class...Ts>
  friend constexpr auto operator!=(types self, types<Ts...> ts )
  ->std::integral_constant<bool, !decltype(self == ts){}>
  { return{}; }
};
template<class...Ts>constexpr types<Ts...> pack{};
```

Now:

```
template<typename... PackA, typename... PackB, typename... PackC>
std::enable_if_t<pack<PackA...> ==pack<PackB...> && pack<PackB...> ==pack<PackC...>>
foo(ClassOne<PackA...>, ClassTwo<PackB...>, ClassThree<PackC...>) { }
```

which reads like english.

Alternatively:

```
template<class...> struct types{
  friend constexpr bool operator==(types,types) { return true; }
  template<class...Ts>
  friend constexpr bool operator==(types,types<Ts...>) { return false; }
  constexpr types(){}
  template<class...Ts>
  friend constexpr bool operator!=(types self, types<Ts...> ts )
  { return !(self==ts); }
};
```

Which is slightly simpler and works similarly.

Comment: Oh very nice, I can use this to expand my type_list class :) thank you.

Comment: I don't really understand the line ->std::integral_constant<bool, !(self==ts)> How are the function arguments allowed to be used in a std integral constant expression? Aren't these run-time arguments?

Comment: @andr sorry, was missing a decltype and has some extra const from an earllier version, where I just returned a `constexpr bool`.